# Changing from GET to POST

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am not an experienced developer but I am currently in an apprenticeship and my senior developer has recently left and im all alone!

I was taught from him that using 'GET' requests was better than 'POST' but after reading up I would like to switch to 'POST' my only problems is I am a little unsure how to modify my code to switch over from 'GET'. I have left a common $scope of our system below. Any help will be great

```
$scope.changenote=function(id,note){
note = encodeURIComponent(note);
var inserthistory = './dbscripts/solicitors/changenote.php?id=' + id + '&user=' + AppStorage.getCurrentUser().username + '&note=' + note;
console.log(inserthistory);
                    $http({method: 'GET', url: inserthistory}).success(function(data) {

       var historyurl = './dbscripts/solicitors/gethistory.php?ref=' + $scope.bbref;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: historyurl
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.histnoteaddbtn = [];
                $scope.history = data;
             $state.go($state.current, {}, {
                    reload: true

            });
    });
 swal("Saved!", "Your note has been saved!", "success")
})
}
```

Comment: Well it's depend on what system are you working on ! I mean it's a CMS or ... ? And well you can't always change GET to POST ! sometimes you need to use each one in some functions ! and about the security, basically there is no different between POST and GET ! in both case you have to use prepared query statement and check the data before using it inside the query !

Comment: @GeomanYabes Shouting? Where?

Comment: **Soheyl**'s comment.. :D always with a `!`

Comment: My bad was looking at OP's post ;)

Comment: They're different semantically - you'd use `GET` to, well, get a resource (the page where the id is 26 for instance) and `POST` to create a resource (e.g. posting a form to generate a webmail) - although because HTML forms only support get and post, post is used for more than that. If you were building a RESTful application though... : http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html In short, with HTML, you don't want someone to be able to create/update/delete a resource by entering something in the address bar - so only use `GET` for reading.

Comment: Get vs post isn't as simple as one is better than the other, more a case that one is more appropriate than the other in given circumstances.  While not set in stone the general guideline is anything that just fetches data should be a get and anything that causes data on the server to change should be a post

Comment: I am using a Telesales system that has been built in house, no CMS system. My problem is my string is to big when sending. Im getting 404 not found error. I think it might be the 'encodeURIComponent'. Only happens when i send strings of 1000+ words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well made, in first case I refactored this codes. I don't know why all this strings are saved into a variable while its never used again in the code. I realy don't know the use of it. I changed your request Methods from `GET` to `POST` here. You may need check your API endpoints and make them listen to an `POST` request. Finaly your code would look like this:

**Note:** The request data is stilled parsed into the URL of your request. To create a RESTful API you should take a look over here [W3C HTTP Method Definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). All request methods are focusing a special usecase.

```
$scope.changenote = function(id,note){
    $http({method:
        'POST',
        url: './dbscripts/solicitors/changenote.php?id=' + id + '&user=' + AppStorage.getCurrentUser().username + '&note=' + encodeURIComponent(note)}
        ).success(function(data) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: './dbscripts/solicitors/gethistory.php?ref=' + $scope.bbref
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.histnoteaddbtn = [];
                $scope.history = data;
                $state.go($state.current, {}, {
                    reload: true

                });
            });
            swal("Saved!", "Your note has been saved!", "success")
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i was unsure how easy that was. Im having a issue sending really big strings to the database. Nightmare!

Comment: @AlexBanerjee you are welcome. You may goging to parse your data into the request body instead of the URL. The URL has many limitations.

Comment: I'm a little unsure how this is done. I thought this is what 'POST' did thats why i wanted to switch over from 'GET'. I start a course next week so hopefully i can learn a little more. Getting thrown into angular, html, and css all at once was a little over whelming xD

Comment: @AlexBanerjee Read about HTTP. First make you self understood how HTTP works it will help you in the future.